# I'm confused about center of mass. need help

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

my friend told me that the object would be moving in total distances of 3.5 , he said that it's because we have to think it using center of mass, but in my mind the center of mass of the object would still be moving at 3 m since it would come to stop once the right side of the object hit the other object or am i missing something?

edit translation: Find the total work.

Comment: What language is that in the picture? You should translate to English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the confusion comes from your diagram. Are there two objects in the picture or is it the same object being moved to a new position? I am pretty sure it is the latter, so I'll answer that.

The force indeed acts on the box's center of mass, and from looking at the distances on the diagram, this center of mass is effectively being displaced by 25cm (half the box's width) + 3m + another 25cm = 3.5m. The work is then quickly calculated as $W = F\times d =(100N) \times (3.5m)$.

If you had to interpret the diagram as two objects, you would have to consider the type of collision, the momenta, etc., but I don't think this is what is being asked here.